# Binding scope object to factory object

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I am connecting to a websocket feed in a factory, which gives me real time bitcoin price data.

I define `service.prices` as an object in `websocketFactory`, and set `wsvm.prices = websocketFactory.prices` in the controller.

The `wsvm.prices.btc` property is not updating in the view, but is logging correctly in console.

code:

factory

```js
app.factory('websocketFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  var service = {}
  service.prices = {
    "btc": 0
  }
  service.gdax = function() {
    const socket = new WebSocket('wss://ws-feed.gdax.com')
    var message = {
      "type": "subscribe",
      "channels": [{
        "name": "ticker",
        "product_ids": [
          "BTC-USD"
        ]
      }, ]
    }

    socket.addEventListener('open', function(event) {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    })

    // Listen for messages
    socket.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      var dataObj = JSON.parse(event.data)
      if (dataObj.price) {
        console.log(dataObj.price) //logging real time data
        service.prices.btc = dataObj.price //this should be updating the view
      }
    });
  }

  return service
}])
```

controller

```js
app.controller('WebsocketController', WebsocketController)
WebsocketController.$inject = ['$scope', 'websocketFactory']

function WebsocketController($scope, websocketFactory) {

  var wsvm = this

  wsvm.prices = websocketFactory.prices
  
  websocketFactory.gdax()

}
```

view

```html
<div ng-controller="PortfolioController as vm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2 style="text-align: center;">Account Balances</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>24h Change</td>
            <td>Total Val USD</td>
            <td>BTC Price</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td ng-class="{change_loss: vm.totals.change_24h_usd < 0, change_win: vm.totals.change_24h_usd > 0}"><b>{{vm.totals.change_24h_usd | currency}}</b></td>
            <td><b>{{vm.totals.total_usd | currency}}</b></td>
            <td ng-controller="WebsocketController as wsvm">{{wsvm.prices.btc}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How to correctly bind factory to controller for real time data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing scope in the socket listener is outside of angular context. Whenever that happens angular needs to be notified to run a digest to update view

Try the following:

```
app.factory('websocketFactory', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
   ......

  socket.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      var dataObj = JSON.parse(event.data)
      if (dataObj.price) {
        console.log(dataObj.price) //logging real time data

        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            service.prices.btc = dataObj.price //this should be updating the view
        });
      }
    });
});
```

I also suggest you look for an angular socket module that will take care of all of this for you internally

Comment: like socket.io?

Comment: Never used it...just did a quick search...something like https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io